# How to fix subquery running too long?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

From [FDIC's website](https://www5.fdic.gov/sod/dynaDownload.asp?barItem=6), I downloaded the CSV file.

I'm using the name of banks **"NAMEFULL"** as the parameter, then *sum* the deposits **"DEPSUMBR"** of all the other banks where the bank is located **"MSABR"**.

I approached this code by building a subquery, but the query takes too long - I would let Access run for an hour, but the query freezes every time.

`SELECT max(NAMEFULL), sum(DEPSUMBR) AS Deposit 
FROM ALL_2018
WHERE MSABR IN (SELECT DISTINCT MSABR 
FROM ALL_2018
WHERE NAMEFULL = [Enter Bank Name]
AND MSABR <> '0')
;`

The output should show the names of other banks that share the MSA as the parameter bank and the sum of the deposits in each MSA.

Below is a screenshot of the csv file

[image]

---

Trying to show MSAs in which Regions has a top 5 ranking by market share:

```
RANK (*) Over (partition by tots.msabr, tots.namefull, order by percentmsashare desc) as Rank
(
SELECT  tots.msabr, tots.namefull, 100 * (tots.summsabra / tots.summsa) as percentmsashare  FROM
(
 SELECT msabra.msabr, msabra.namefull, msabra.summsabra, msa.summsa FROM
 (
  SELECT msabr, namefull, sum(depsumbr) as summsabra
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr, namefull
 ) msabra
 INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT msabr, sum(depsumbr) as summsa
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr
 ) msa
 ON msabra.msabr = msa.msabr
) tots
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT distinct msabr
  FROM ALL_2018 
  WHERE namefull = 'Regions bank' and msabr > '0'
) bnks 
ON tots.msabr = bnks.msabr
)
```

Comment: I'm on a cellphone and cannot download this csv data to see what it looks like. By NAMEFULL did you mean NAMEBR? By "sum of the deposits in each MSA" did you mean "sum of the deposits in each bank in the MSA". Could you add a snippet of the csv data to the question?

Comment: Hey Caius, thank you so much for taking a look! I think NAMEFULL is more comprehensive than NAMEBR since NAMEBR can mix up JP Morgan versus JP Morgan Chase for example. Yes by "sum of the deposits in each MSA", I meant "sum of the deposits in each bank in the MSA". I cleaned some of the data but I added a snapshot on to the original question for reference.

Comment: This was a trip down memory lane; pulled out an old machine with access on it and imported the 2018 data(approx 53mb) and tried a few things/ results below

Comment: @hbk239 Is `ALL_2018` an Access table containing the data imported from the CSV file, or is a link to the CSV file.  If not already, make it a table with the `MSABR` and `NAMEFULL` fields indexed.

Comment: That's worth noting; for my query scratch I imported the csv into access proper, rather than linking

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to make this a messy, unexplained code only answer. It ran in a few seconds in access 2010 on an old ibm t60p, even without indexes, if we use an inner join rather than IN to filter to "only banks that have an msabr in the list of msabr relevant to the desired bank"

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT msabr, namefull, sum(depsumbr) as sumdep 
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr, namefull
) sums
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT distinct msabr
  FROM ALL_2018 
  WHERE namefull = 'Regions bank' and msabr > 0
) bnks 
ON sums.msabr = bnks.msabr
```

I couldn't tell if you wanted sum per msabr/branch pairing  in your output or just sum per branch. If it's just branch either group again in the outer (replace the `select *` with `select nameful, sum(sumdep) ... group by namefull`) or try this form:

```
SELECT d.namefull, sum(d.depsumbr) as sumdep
FROM all_2018 d
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT distinct msabr
  FROM ALL_2018 
  WHERE namefull = 'Regions bank' and msabr > 0
) bnks 
ON d.msabr = bnks.msabr
GROUP BY d.namefull
```

If you wanted sum by msa, change the grouping in the sums subquery of the first form so it doesn't mention branch. To modify the second form for msa instead of branch swap it out of the outer select/group by

I don't know how the second query performs as I wrote it on a cell phone; it's untested

---

Here's a query that sort of answers your two questions in the comments:

```
SELECT tots.msabr, tots.namefull, 100 * (tots.summsabra / tots.summsa) as percentmsashare  FROM
(
 SELECT msabra.msabr, msabra.namefull, msabra.summsabra, msa.summsa FROM
 (
  SELECT msabr, namefull, sum(depsumbr) as summsabra
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr, namefull
 ) msabra

 INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT msabr, sum(depsumbr) as summsa
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr
 ) msa
 ON msabra.msabr = msa.msabr
) tots
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT distinct msabr
  FROM ALL_2018 
  WHERE namefull = 'Regions bank' and msabr > 0
) bnks 
ON tots.msabr = bnks.msabr

ORDER BY tots.msabr ASC, tots.summsabra / tots.summsa DESC
```

It shows all the banks in an MSA orderby descending market share of sum of deposits in the MSA. to do this it groups the data at two different levels: per-bank-per-msa and per-msa, then the percentage is given by (perbankmsa / permsa)

It looks like:

[image]

I can think of some ways to strip out anything afte rthe top 5, but this query would be better done in a more powerful db.  For now I would use the front end to ignore any rows after the first 5 per msa in this list - that deals with question 2

Question 1, the market shares of Regions bank would be simpler: remove the `INNER JOIN(...)bnks ON ...` and add a WHERE clause above the ORDER BY, that says `WHERE tots.namefull = 'Regions bank'` - the entire process access goes through is hence: calc the sum for all msa, calc the sum for all bank-msa, join together, restrict to only those rows where 'regions bank' is mentioned. Because the market share of every bank per msa is calced before the filtering down to just 'regions bank' we get the true percentage for 'regions bank' alone in that msa. If we filtered to 'regions bank' before we calced sums, then 'regions bank' would have 100% of every MSA because we filtered out all competing rows before we grouped/summed

```
SELECT tots.msabr, tots.namefull, 100 * (tots.summsabra / tots.summsa) as percentmsashare  FROM
(
 SELECT msabra.msabr, msabra.namefull, msabra.summsabra, msa.summsa FROM
 (
  SELECT msabr, namefull, sum(depsumbr) as summsabra
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr, namefull
 ) msabra

 INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT msabr, sum(depsumbr) as summsa
  FROM all_2018 
  GROUP BY msabr
 ) msa
 ON msabra.msabr = msa.msabr
) tots
WHERE tots.namefull = 'Regions bank'
```

Technically we don't need the outer select; the where clause and summing could be pushed into tots and tots be done away with. It just ended up this way as a modification of the earlier query that needed to join 3 tables (and access can only join two at a time - again, the select is superfluous, I could have just bracketed the joins - `select * from (a join b) join c` versus `select * from (select * from a join b) join c` - i tend to do the latter because most of my work is in DBs that wouldn't accept the former)

---

OK, so I talked about cartesian product in the comments, to give a ranking. It's nasty, but it works like this. Suppose we have the following athletics scores:

```
Name, Event, Seconds
Usain, 100m, 9.0
Jonno, 100m, 10.1
Timmy, 100m, 11.3
Roger, 400m, 41.3
Salva, 400m, 42.1
Erdoh, 400m, 44.0
```

If we run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  scores s1
  INNER JOIN scores s2 ON s1.event = s2.event and s1.time <= s2.time
```

Then the `<=` will cause rows to multiply:

```
s1Name, s1Event, s1Seconds, s2Name, s2Event, s2Seconds
Usain, 100m, 9.0, Usain, 100m, 9.0
Jonno, 100m, 10.1, Usain, 100m, 9.0
Jonno, 100m, 10.1, Jonno, 100m, 10.1
Timmy, 100m, 11.3, Usain, 100m, 9.0
Timmy, 100m, 11.3, Jonno, 100m, 10.1
Timmy, 100m, 11.3, Timmy, 100m, 11.3
```

There is only 1 usain row; only one person is equal to or faster than usain, and that's usain. There are two jonno rows; usain is faster so his time is `<` less than. Jonno is equal to Jonno. Both Usain and Jonno are faster than Timmy, so we end up with a Timmy row matched with usain, and timmy matched with jonno, and timmy matched with himself

You'll hence note that Usain has 1 row, and he's number 1 in the race. Jonn has 2 rows and is in 2nd place. Timmy has 3 rows and is third. If we hence group on only the s1 data and count it, we get a ranking:

```
SELECT s1.Name, s1.Event, s1.Time, count(*) as ranking 
FROM
  scores s1
  INNER JOIN scores s2 ON s1.event = s2.event and s1.time <= s2.time
GROUP BY
  s1.Name, s1.Event, s1.Time

s1Name, s1Event, s1Seconds, ranking
Usain, 100m,  9.0, 1
Jonno, 100m, 10.1, 2
Timmy, 100m, 11.3, 3
```

Now, your main query that is working out the overall percentages of market shares etc is big and ugly already; I wouldn't make it bigger and uglier by pasting it all in twice so it can be joined to itself.. Maybe make a view (`CREATE VIEW AS [big ugly select statement]`) and then write another query that joins the view to itself

Remember: you probably need to do this ranking trick BEFORE you filter down to "just regions bank" because you want to rank ALL the banks and then select only those where "regions bank" is the name and `<=5`  is the ranking

Comment: Caius - really appreciate your expertise here. I do have a couple follow-up questions that relate to the query you just created: 1) how would I show % market share that 'regions bank' in your example has in each MSA? 2) how would I show the MSAs in which regions bank has a top 5 ranking?

Comment: ooof,,, Access probably isn't the best tool for this job; what is your appetite for loading it into a free version of SQL server that runs locally? Must it be access?

Comment: You're the GOAT Caius - I think Access is the only data science toolset that we use in our office... I'll digest the second answer tonight and revert with any follow-up questions. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Caius - I added a follow-up question below regarding the ranking issue. I would really appreciate your help if you have capacity!

Comment: I'm trying to toy around "rank" and "Partition by" to approach the first question of showing msas in which regions bank has a top 5 ranking in market share

Comment: I don't think you'll succeed; access doesn't have analytic/window functions. Have you switched to using a more serious db?

Comment: You could do it with a cartesian product. I'll make an additional edit to explain the concept

Comment: I just realized that access does not let me use rank... what about something similar to the below?                                                         SELECT tbl1.SalesPerson , count(*) AS Rank 
FROM tbl AS tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl AS tbl2 ON tbl1.DEPT = tbl2.DEPT 
    AND tbl1.#Customers < tbl2.#Customers 
GROUP BY tbl1.SalesPerson

Comment: That is indeed pretty much the edit I made. Note that in your case the ranking will probably be done by >= unless you're happy to turn things round in your head to use <. Personally I think it makes more sense to say `select wanted.* FROM banks wanted inner join banks ignore ON ... AND wanted.marketshare >= ignore.marketshare`

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` is often faster than `IN`, particularly with the right indexes.  So, write the query as:

```
SELECT max(NAMEFULL), sum(DEPSUMBR) AS Deposit 
FROM ALL_2018 as a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ALL_2018 as a2
              WHERE a2.MSABR = a.MSABR AND
                    a2.NAMEFULL = [Enter Bank Name]
             ) AND
      a.MSABR <> '0';
```

The right index would be `ALL_2018(MSABR, NUMEFULL)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Unfortunately, I'm getting a syntax error - I tried moving the last line within the parenthesis but that doesn't seem to help. Is there another way to write the code above?